# Positive pay (AX 2012)

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I am trying to implement standard dynamics AX positive pay functionality that comes with Dynamics AX 2012 Cumulative update 6.

I am trying to setup positive as per [this documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269119.aspx).

I can successfully implement all the steps except step 2 where I have to give the link to xslt file. As I have never used any xsl file before, I do not know where to start from.

Is there any built in xsl file which I can use or any hint on creating the new one if I have to?

Comment: That link looks broken. What's the fill link?

Comment: Sorry, it's http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269119.aspx

Comment: Thanks Alok, I'll take a look at it after my scrum.

Answer (score 1):

XSL is basically a transform between XML and a stylized display of said XML document. IE you'll pass payee, amount, date, ect... via an XML and the XSLT will apply it to a template, much like CSS.

Visual Studio has an editor that you can use to make the XSL. It's under the drop down >XML. There's also other 3rd party editors that can help. To get a quick idea of how it works this W3Schools link has a neat online editor: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

You'll basically just want to lay it out like you'd want the check to print. Here's a good article about XSL/T files.
http://scottsjewels.blogspot.com/2011/04/occasional-xslt-for-everyday-developer.html

Comment: Hi Kevin, Thank you for your reply. The problem now is basically I am not being able to generate the positive payment file. I am using the already existing xslt file in resources node in AOT. But the positive payment file is somehow not being stored in the output folder. The batch job now runs without error. I have went through steps in this document. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269119.aspx  and http://technet.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg232194.aspx. Hopefully I can figure it out soon.

Comment: I made some progress with XSLT and am able to transform the XML To another XML file. Now, the requirement is that the positive pay file should be of type .txt with plain text inside it. But what AX does is just transform it to XML file. I used the "text" attribute in XSLT file which works fine in visual studio but not in AX 2012. Any idea on generating .txt instead of XML using XSLT?